# How do you overload Arithmetic operators in the Processing Language?

Tags: processing

I understand that it is based on java but there were rumors that overloading operators would be part of the project. Are they? and if so how is it done?

Comment: AFAIK java doesn't support operator overloading. You could use Processing like syntax in other languages that do support operator overloading (for example Python or Kotlin)

Comment: You cannot, but you can write methods like `.isEqual()` and so on to achieve a similar result.